# Load .svg images from URL

Tags: swift, svg, loadimage

Can I load .svg images from URL with library SDWebImage? I found SVGKit but it's not performant,too buggy and load images in webviews.
I need the best practice. thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

Few thoughts on this subject:

**1) Way** SVG TO PNG API

You load image using http request and get url to transformed SVG TO PNG image.
Try to find services

**2) Way** SVG TO PNG html+JS

You can add your html file with SVG TO PNG js to our project. I do not know js, but swift code will be:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var webView = UIWebView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView = UIWebView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    view.addSubview(webView)

    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("SvgToPng", withExtension:"html")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
}
```

and html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<script>
....
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**3) Way** GCDWebServer (https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer)

You can make local serve and create your own script (it can de more powerful than 2 way).

Comment: Also your can build your own translator. You will load base64 data and transform to png. Right now, only webView can display svg. So, you need to transform anyway

Comment: I was obliged to use UIWebView . but it worked like a charm

Comment: You need to have a good html+js file, which will display svg file correctly in webView. E.g., you will have base html code string, where you can edit params and then you will send it to webView using webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)

Comment: If my answer helped you, please, mark it. Thank you)